# Alpha not working on reference image

Tags: transparency

I'm following this beginners course but and we should make the reference image transparent, but it doesn't do anything for me. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: haha.. me too following same course and stuck at the same point. Did you figured it out why ? Iam using Blender 2.8 for mac

Comment: Mobin's answer solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

**FOR BLENDER 2.80 to pre 2.92:**

Go to object data properties and select alpha and change the slider.
[image]
.

**FOR BLENDER +2.92:**

Same as before, go to object data properties and select opacity (they renamed it) and change the slider.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Blender 2.92.0 version. Go to Object data properties, then opacity.
[image: Fix blender reference background image opacity/alpha]